# Get specific controls a list of controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, list, controls

I have a list of controls that get a `groupbox`, in which there `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, `CheckBox`.

When getting the list nececito differentiate and get the name of each control I tested with this code.

```
private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Control> lstControles =
            new List<Control>(groupBox1.Controls.OfType<Control>().OrderBy(x => x.Name));

        TextBoxUniversal txt = new TextBoxUniversal();
        EntitySelectorCombo cbo = new EntitySelectorCombo();
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();

        foreach (var item in lstControles)
        {
             if(txt == item.Controls.OfType<TextBoxUniversal>())


             if (cbo == item.Controls.OfType<EntitySelectorCombo>())

             if (chk == item.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())

        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is hard to determine what you are asking, what is your question? Please translate your entire post to English as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it the wrong way (your code compares each object from list with newly instantiated object by reference, which always return a `false` result).

Try using [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator to check object type compatibility :

```
foreach (var item in lstControles)
{
     if(item is TextBoxUniversal)
        .......

     if (item is EntitySelectorCombo)
        .......

     if (item is CheckBox)
        .......
}
```

Comment: Ok I will test the code, I set up a query as to the answers to come to me email?